# How to stop TexStudio from creating 100 backup files?

Tags: texstudio, windows

I use TexStudio for Windows 10. Whenever I save a file, it creates a backup file with an extension "txs~NN" where NN is a number between 00 and 99. This fills my folder with many unneeded files. Moreover, after 100 saves I start getting annoying messages saying that a backup cannot be created (probably, because it has used all numbers between 00 and 99). How can I disable this behavior?

Here are some screenshots of configuration screens:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Related (but that question does not really have an answer): https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292620/texstudio-creating-a-backup-of-the-file-failed

Comment: *Why*-type questions — such as the one contained in the title of your query — probably cannot be answered conclusively, and they run the risk of inviting uninformed bloviating. Please consider rephrasing your query so that it sounds less like a rant.

Comment: BTW, congrats on achieving 5000 rep points on TeX.SE!

Comment: Which OS and the version of texstudio are you using?

Comment: Windows 10, TexStudio version 2.12.10

Comment: Where exactly it makes backup files? I don't see any for my files.

Comment: [New version 3.0.1](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/releases/download/3.0.1/texstudio-3.0.1-win-qt5.exe)

Comment: Can you share screenshot of your Texstudio specially `Option--> Configure TeXstudio...--> SVN` and `Macro-->Edit macros` windows?

Comment: @C.F.G added screenshots

Comment: Well, Your setting is as mine. (v2.12.16)  Probably if you update your editor it will treat as you want.

Comment: [Here is completely related (I think) discussion.](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/discussion/907840/thread/64cd1328/)